# java.lang.IllegalAccessException: no such method: rubyjit.<name>Serializer$$_fast_attributes

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, active-model-serializers

Seeing this error quite frequently.
Jruby 1.7.13
Ubuntu 14.
Sun Java 8 _05

ps -ef command for the process:

```
java -Xmx786m -Xss2048k -Djffi.boot.library.path=/home/ubuntu/server/tools/jruby/lib/jni -Xmn128m -server -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/ubuntu/server/tools/jruby/lib/jruby.jar -classpath : -Djruby.home=/home/ubuntu/server/tools/jruby -Djruby.lib=/home/ubuntu/server/tools/jruby/lib -Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=/bin/sh org.jruby.Main bin/rails s -p4005 -e production
```

Any idea what is causing that error infrequently.

```
Java::JavaLang::RuntimeException (com.headius.invokebinder.InvalidTransformException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: no such method: rubyjit.ContactSerializer$$fast_attributes_a0671ee9e02931c7660594220ffed4d4fc58cad5681842940.__file_(ContactSerializer$$fast_attributes_a0671ee9e02931c7660594220ffed4d4fc58cad5681842940,ThreadContext,IRubyObject,Block)IRubyObject/invokeStatic):
org.jruby.runtime.invokedynamic.InvocationLinker.createRubyHandle(InvocationLinker.java:1689)
org.jruby.runtime.invokedynamic.InvocationLinker.access$900(InvocationLinker.java:75)
org.jruby.runtime.invokedynamic.InvocationLinker$RubyCallGenerator.generate(InvocationLinker.java:715)
org.jruby.runtime.invokedynamic.InvocationLinker.tryDispatchDirect(InvocationLinker.java:765)
org.jruby.runtime.invokedynamic.InvocationLinker.getTarget(InvocationLinker.java:775)
org.jruby.runtime.invokedynamic.InvocationLinker.invocationFallback(InvocationLinker.java:137)
rubyjit.ActiveModel::Serializer$$attributes_dbeb427ba2b0518d676c0a687aeb474a438bbc8b681842940.chained_0_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file_(active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/serializer.rb:454)
rubyjit.ActiveModel::Serializer$$attributes_dbeb427ba2b0518d676c0a687aeb474a438bbc8b681842940.file(active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/serializer.rb)
rubyjit.ActiveModel::Serializer$$serializable_hash_77c90db1574839863dc0d7ab15cb761d318d3fad681842940.__file_(active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/serializer.rb:478)
rubyjit.ActiveModel::Serializer$$serializable_hash_15164681ef3759650116133c60c86faa4d0da16f681842940.file(active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/serializer.rb:360)
rubyjit.ActiveModel::ArraySerializer$$serializable_array_3e75f1b3d701c37c0dd6c09012f195834f37a85e681842940.block_0$RUBY$__file_(active_model_serializers (0.8.1) lib/active_model/array_serializer.rb:89)
rubyjit$ActiveModel::ArraySerializer$$serializable_array_3e75f1b3d701c37c0dd6c09012f195834f37a85e681842940$block_0$RUBY$__file_.call(rubyjit$ActiveModel::ArraySerializer$$serializable_array_3e75f1b3d701c37c0dd6c09012f195834f37a85e681842940$block_0$RUBY$__file_)
org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.yield(CompiledBlock19.java:135)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142)
org.jruby.RubyArray.collect(RubyArray.java:2399)
org.jruby.RubyArray.map19(RubyArray.java:2412)
org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$map19.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$map19.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:458)
```

Answer (score 2):

would be great if you can come up with a piece of script where this gets reproduced (and submit it to JRuby's issue tracker) as this is invoke-dynamic related, which gets turned on for you due Java 8.

work-around would be (unless you get other advice what the failure actually means - if it's fine to live with) to disable indy :

```
java -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx786m -Xss2048k ...
```

or if you're about to use the `jruby` executable :

```
jruby -Xcompile.invokedynamic=false -S ...
```

both can be added to their corresponding **XXX_OPTS** environment variable